# Magento 2.3.1 Add configurable products - all product pages show the same attributes

Tags: magento2.3.1

[image]

Add configurable products, the size and color will appear on the new page of each product, which makes me very distressed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed annoying, but if you are not using these attributes, you can:

A. go to admin **Stores -> Attributes -> Product -> select the attribute -> scroll down to Advanced Attribute Properties -> Scope** and change the scope into anything but 'global'
B. you can simply remove them from the attribute set **Stores -> Attributes -> Attribute Set -> choose your attribute set and unassign the attribute**.